# How to return data from an api consumed by nodejs to the frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The API I am trying to consume is from a third party and it blocks Cross-Origin, so I can not consume it with jquery, nor javascript ... So I had to create a script in nodejs to consume this API ...

I would like to know how do I consume this data that nodejs got from the API to my frontend, using javascript?

Remembering that this nodejs is in a separate file from my frontend and running from another server.

```
var request = require("../../node_modules/request");
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://....apimanagement.us2.hana.ondemand.com/bot/v1/...',
  qs: { Shop: '..'', PeriodoAte: '...' },
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '822e513f-da5e-4a0b-b403-1dd8fa46e86f',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     authorization: 'Basic .........',
     apikey: '....',
     'content-type': 'application/json' },
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Comment: You will have to make your script able to serve http requests and have your front end hit it with an AJAX request. If you want to do this as a toy then just use express or hapi and follow a relevant tutorial. If you want to do it for real (as in production) then the answer is beyond the scope of stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One path would be:

- pick a node framework (Express, Hapi, ...) lets pick Hapi for this example
- read the getting started guide https://hapijs.com/tutorials/getting-started
- learn about promises or go through callback hell
- end up with something like this for testing

  ```
  'use strict';

  const Hapi = require('hapi');
  const rp = require('request-promise');

  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost'
  });


  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, h) => {

      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'https://./..',
        qs: {Shop: '..', PeriodoAte: '...'},
        headers: {
          'postman-token': '822e513f-da5e-4a0b-b403-1dd8fa46e86f',
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
          authorization: 'Basic .........',
          apikey: '...',
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
      };


      return rp(options).catch(e => {
        console.log(`api call failed ${e}`);
        return 'fail';
      })
    }
  });

  const init = async () => {

    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
  };

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  init();
  ```
- now you can start it with node and visit 'localhost:3000/'
- read more, try more
- read about node production mode and hosting

Something like that, hope it helps a bit

EDIT: //

to consume on client just use for example jquery to fetch the route served with the code above

Here is some client example as requested in the comments:

If you are serving your html from another location, not the hapi api, you will need to enable cors in the HapiJS route.

```
     server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
            cors: {
                origin: ['*'],
                additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with']
            }
        },
```

Then one way to consume this endpoint would be jquery

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" id="Button" value="Fetch"/>
    <div id='main'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button').click(() => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:3000/info", success: (result) => {
                        $("#main").text(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I found your answer very good, but could you complete her by giving an example of how I consume her on the client? But I'll give you the punctuation anyway.

Comment: I've added a jquery example

Answer (score 0):

You need a web server listening for requests in order to communicate your frontend with your backend (Node.js). You could use [Express](https://expressjs.com) if you want something simple. You could also use a JavaScript framework, there are many ([Sails.js](https://sailsjs.com) would be a good option to get started fast).

If you can't install Node.js in your server, another option would be using AWS Lambda to quickly create an API that you can consume from your frontend through an HTTP request.

Comment: It's a new path I'm walking, could you report me so I can look and learn? -